# [ Laravel 5.2 ]Storage file not found even if it exists

Tags: php, laravel, storage, file-not-found

```
\Storage::disk('verify_files')->put('verify-' . $fileCode[3], $fileCode[0]);

    $attach = \Storage::get(storage_path('app/public/verify') . '/' . 'verify-' . $fileCode[3]);
```

I am using the code above to generate and fetch the file.

Here is the filesystem I use:

```
'verify_files' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/verify'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

When I test it with file_exists(), it returns true but laravel returns `FileNotFoundException in FilesystemAdapter.php line 61:`

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

The `get` method of the Storage facade will automatically look into the directory of the default disk. In this case, you are passing in the absolute path to the file using `storage_path`, which is redundant because it will look inside the `storage/app` directory as it is.

Instead, do `Storage::disk('verify_files')->get('verify-' . $fileCode[3])`;

Use `storage_path` when you need absolute paths to files and directories.

Comment: I passed the path instead of using the Storage facade and process it from there. I will update you when your answer works. Thanks!

Comment: Almost a month and I forgot to update.

The problem was ->get() fetches the content.

I fetched the file with something like storage_path('app/public/verify') . "/" . $file

If there's a better solution, please do tell!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you, except I've been using a different method to you:

```
            $parse = new Parsedown();
            $url = url('about.md'); // This would fail, because it returns absolute
            $url = 'about.md'; // the file is living in the root directory of public. This would succeed, because it's relative

            try { // catch file not found errors
                $about = File::get($url);
            } catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $exception) {
                die ('Bad File');
            }

            echo $parse->text($about);
```

This came from a combination of [this page](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/126/getting-the-contents-of-a-file) and when @SArnab above mentioned about the path not needing to be absolute.

Besides me using a different method, the only problem I had before was that I was using an absolute path rather than a relative one which I'm using now.

I just thought I'd add in this alternative method to getting file contents in Laravel 5.2.

Enjoy!